# htaccess force https non-www in single redirect for all pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect everybody to my https:// site (not https://www) and force HTTPS in single redirect. My relevant parts of .htaccess:

```
# Check if HTTPS and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off
# Force HTTPS and remove WWW
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

## The problem? It doesn't work for sub-pages!

While it does work for main page (eg. http://www.example.com redirects to https://example.com), it doesn't work for sub-pages (eg. http://www.example.com/contact sholud redirect me to https://example.com/contact but only www is removed and I end up on non-https site: http://example.com/contact).

How to change my .htaccess rules, to force HTTPS and remove WWW for my site and all pages of the site in single redirect?

## After changes: it works for sub-pages, but in 2 redirects. Can it be done in only one?

Thanks to answer by Nisarg and [some digging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256038/htaccess-https-redirect-from-www-to-non-www), my site now properly redirects to HTTPS even on sub-pages. Yay!
Relevant .htaccess code now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =off   [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

# remaining htaccess mod_rewrite CODE for WordPress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately, it takes 2 steps to process. So, the question is still up: **can it be done in 1 redirect**?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:(Guessing you are using `index.php`)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

#
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Yup, I'm using `index.php`. I modified Your code (Your example redirects to www - I want the opposite ;) and it works: even when wisiting http://www.example.com/contact I was redirected to https://example.com/contact but **it was done using 3 redirects** - any suggestions, how to achieve all this in only one redirect?

Comment: Glad to hear that it works. if you think, the answer is useful, up the vote.

Comment: It's useful, as it gets the job done, but doing it in 3 redirects isn't optimal from speed and SEO points of view...